# How to mask a polars dataframe using another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe like so:

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    'time': [datetime(2021, 10, 2, 0, 5), datetime(2021, 10, 2, 0, 10)],
    '1': [2.9048, 48224.0],
    '2': [2.8849, 48068.0]
})
```

and a masking dataframe with similar columns and time value like so:

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    'time': [datetime(2021, 10, 2, 0, 5), datetime(2021, 10, 2, 0, 10)],
    '1': [False, True],
    '2': [False, True]
})
```

I am looking for this result:

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    'time': [datetime(2021, 10, 2, 0, 5), datetime(2021, 10, 2, 0, 10)],
    '1': [None, 2.8849],
    '2': [None, 48068.0],
})
```

Here I only show with 2 columns '1' and '2' but there could any number of them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having columns in a single `DataFrame` has guarantees you don't have when you have data in separate tables.

Masking out values by columns in another `DataFrame` is a potential for errors caused by different lengths. For this reason polars does not encourage such operations and therefore you must first create a single `DataFrame` from the two, and then `select` the columns/computations you need.

So let's do that.

The first thing you can do is `join` the two tables. This guaranteed to work on `DataFrame`s of different sizes.

```py
df_a.join(df_mask, on="time", suffix="_mask")
```

This comes however with a price, as joining is not free.

If you are 100% certain your dataframes have the same height, you can use a horizontal `concat`.

```py
(
    pl.concat(
        [df_a, df_mask.select(pl.all().suffix("_mask"))], how="horizontal"
    ).select(
        [pl.col("time")]
        + [
            pl.when(pl.col(f"{name}_mask")).then(pl.col(name)).otherwise(None)
            for name in ["1", "2"]
        ]
    )
)
```

In the final `select` query we take the columns we want. And compute the masked values with a `when -> then -> otherwise` branch.

This outputs:

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ time                ┆ 1       ┆ 2       │
│ ---                 ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64     ┆ f64     │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2021-10-02 00:05:00 ┆ null    ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-10-02 00:10:00 ┆ 48224.0 ┆ 48068.0 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```