# Compare two Pola-rs dataframes by position

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rust, rust-polars

Suppose I have two dataframes like:

```rust
let df_1 = df! {
        "1" => [1,   2,   2,   3,   4,   3],
        "2" => [1,   4,   2,   3,   4,   3],
        "3" => [1,   2,   6,   3,   4,   3],
    }
    .unwrap();

    let mut df_2 = df_1.clone();
    for idx in 0..df_2.width() {
        df_2.apply_at_idx(idx, |s| {
            s.cummax(false)
                .shift(1)
                .fill_null(FillNullStrategy::Zero)
                .unwrap()
        })
        .unwrap();
    }

    println!("{:#?}", df_1);
    println!("{:#?}", df_2);

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32 ┆ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 4   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i32 ┆ i32 ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

and I want to compare them such that I end up with a boolean dataframe I can use as a predicate for a selection and aggregation:

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 3     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ true  ┆ false ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ true  ┆ false ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ true  ┆ true  ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ false ┆ false ┆ false │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

In Python Pandas I might do `df.where(df_1.ge(df_2)).sum().sum()`. What's the idiomatic way to do that with Rust Pola-rs?

Comment: AOC 2022 Day 8? :D I feel your pain. I did it with `ndarray`

Comment: Anyway, you're only summing over bool arrays to count how many values are true. Can't you just use `somethingsomething.iter().filter(|x| x == true).count()`?

Comment: Not quite, I'm summing integer values where  the corresponding bool dataframe is true. I guess I could convert that and iterate over but at that point there's not much benefit in using the dataframe in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<edit>**

If you actually have a single dataframe you can do:

```
let mask = 
    when(all().gt_eq(
            all().cummax(false).shift(1).fill_null(0)))
    .then(all())
    .otherwise(lit(NULL));

let out = 
    df_1.lazy().select(&[mask])
    //.sum()
    .collect();
```

**</edit>**

---

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/72899438

> Masking out values by columns in another DataFrame is a potential for errors
> caused by different lengths. For this reason polars does not encourage such
> operations

It appears the recommended way is to add a suffix to one of the dataframes, "concat" them and use `when/then/otherwise`.

[`.with_context()`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.LazyFrame.html#method.with_context) has been added since that answer which can be used to access both dataframes.

In Python:

```
df1.lazy().with_context(
   df2.lazy().select(pl.all().suffix("_right"))
).select([
   pl.when(pl.col(name) >= pl.col(f"{name}_right"))
     .then(pl.col(name)) 
   for name in df1.columns
]).collect()
```

I've not used rust - but my attempt at a translation:

```
let mask = 
   df_1.get_column_names().iter().map(|name| 
      when(col(name).gt_eq(col(&format!("{name}_right"))))
      .then(col(name))
      .otherwise(lit(NULL))
   ).collect::<Vec<Expr>>();

let out = 
    df_1.lazy()
    .with_context(&[
        df_2.lazy().select(&[all().suffix("_right")])
    ])
    .select(&mask)
    //.sum()
    .collect();

println!("{:#?}", out);
```

Output:

```
Ok(shape: (6, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ 1    ┆ 2    ┆ 3    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i32  ┆ i32  ┆ i32  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 4    ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ null ┆ 6    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ null ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ 4    ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ null ┆ null │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘)
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me the longest time to figure out how to even do elementwise addition in `polars`. I guess that's just not the "normal" way to use these things as in principle the columns can have different data types.

You can't call `zip` and `map` on the dataframe directly. That doesn't work.

But. `df` has a method `iter()` that gives you an iterater over all the columns. The columns are `Series`, and for *those* you have all sorts of elementwise operations implemented.

Long story short

```rust
let df = df!("A" => &[1, 2, 3], "B" => &[4, 5, 6]).unwrap();
let df2 = df!("A" => &[6, 5, 4], "B" => &[3, 2, 1]).unwrap();

let df3 = DataFrame::new(
            df.iter()
              .zip(df2.iter())
              .map(|(series1, series2)| series1.gt(series2).unwrap())
              .collect());
```

That gives you your boolean array. From here, I assume it should be possible to figure out how to use that for indexing. Probably another use of `df.iter().zip(df3)` or whatever.

Comment: It seems the Python API does have these methods, e.g. df_1 > df_2 https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/7d26e6c0a8ce105d11129385f7dce09d3df0faa3/py-polars/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py#L996 though they loop over the series in a similar way to your answer under the hood and don't seem to exist in the Rust API. Looks like this is the only way currently.